# ASP .Net MVC User ownership and authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a MVC newbie and trying to build a simple web app where users can register and log in (already kinda done with the Identity sample for MVC) and also create some objects (for example, to do items in a list) that are basically bound to them, unless they state otherwise.

Basically, if not stated otherwise, a to do item cannot be seen or edited by other users.

The first step I'm trying to get done is to populate the list only with my users' items.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity), It'll handle any of your registration and user management, you can even define [roles](http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/11/asp-net-identity-2-1-roles-based-authorization-authentication-asp-net-web-api/) and [claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims) based on what you want. Now Lets say you have a model like below and you want to make sure the entity is built by a defined user, you include UserId to your model as a foreign key so it'll be defined by this user for example:

```
public class CustomModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ObjectExample { get; set; }
    public string ObjectExample2 { get; set; }
    //FK to user
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Anytime you want to Get the Value of UserId you can call the identity methods to get the userId like below:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

Hope this gives you an idea.

**UPDATE**

Lets say you want to insert first set of data to your database and it has to be defined by a user. then you have to fill your model like below:

```
var entity = new CustomModel
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    ObjectExample = "string",
    ObjectExample2 = "secString",
    UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId() //Identity Lib will provide this method for you
};
using(MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
{
    context.CustomModel.Add(entity); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me on the right track! Just a quick follow-up question: When I create an object, how do I automatically set my userId to it?

Comment: @Iris Are you using Entity framework code first or Database first?

Comment: I think I got it by myself! Inside the Create method I set item.user_id = User.Identity.GetUserId();. Is this an okay method?

Comment: @Iris i explained using first insert to database :)

Comment: @Iris indeed it gives you the value of userid

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it helped me to understand this a little bit better :)

Comment: @Iris my pleasure :)

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion it is more of an application logic and not authorization. The simplest way to implement it is to query items that were created by current logged in user when you want to display those items or edit them.

Authorization is not about displaying specific user content (it is a personalization) but about allowing/restricting users to access specific pages or perform specific actions on the portal based on information about the user and set of predefined authorization rules. Here are couple of examples:

1. Only admin users are allowed to see/edit some content (role based authorization)
2. Allow access to users that are older that 18 years old (claim based authorization)
3. Only users from specific geo-location (again claim based)

As you see from the examples authorization is less suitable for filtering rows that get from data base (as in your case).

Rule of thumb could be trying to mark an action or a page with authorization attribute. So if you want do "personalized authorization" you will have to create action/page per user, which is not what you are trying to do right?

Comment: well explained.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely need to inform myself more on authorization and related matters!